# ebay api, change fixed price item to auction

Tags: ebay-api

Using the site, it's possible to "send an item to auction", that is, convert a `FixedPriceItem` to a `Chinese` auction - as far as I know, this does not relist the item. Is this possible using the api, or is the only way to `endItem` then `addItem`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the Fixed Price listing to auction price listing, Only way is to end the listing and list again using AddItem call .
https://pages.ebay.in/help/sell/revising_restrictions.html.

Comment: yeah, I've seen that and the API docs say the same thing - you can't change the listing format in `reviseItem`, however, the api is drastically changing with lots of cross-over from the new API's that have been introduced and I've found many places where the docs are out of date!